# Real-time blockquote animation

Tags: jquery

What's the proper way of doing `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` on this? It's just blinking.

Here's my code:

**html**

```
<blockquote id="reviews">
     <p id="review_content"></p>
     <footer><a href="#" id="review_url"></a></footer>
 </blockquote>
```

**jquery**

```
var reviews = [{
    content: "To err is human; to forgive, divine.",
    user: "Alexander Pope",
    url: "http://www.example.com"
}, {
    content: "Reports of my death have been greatly exaggerated.",
    user: "Mark Twain",
    url: "http://www.example.com"
}, {
    content: "A line of oversize watches that can offer many of the attributes of premium luxury watches at an affordable price.",
    user: "Horozima",
    url: "http://www.horozima.com/2012/07/terranaut-xl-50mm.html"
}];

var interval = 4000; // 4sec interval

(function change() {

    var randomReview = Math.floor(Math.random() * reviews.length)

    var reviewContent = $('#review_content', '#reviews').text(reviews[randomReview].content);
    var reviewUser = $('footer a#review_url', '#reviews').attr('href', reviews[randomReview].url).text(reviews[randomReview].user);

    function updateText() {
        reviewContent.fadeIn();
        reviewUser.fadeIn();
    }

    function dismisText() {
        reviewContent.fadeOut();
        reviewUser.fadeOut();
    }

    updateText();
    dismisText();

    setTimeout(change, interval);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The *blinking* behavior is due to the fact that jQuery animations always run in parallel (except if you don't want them to be so).

You can use the callback feature of the `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` functions to exhibit chained effect on the animations:

```
reviewContent.fadeOut(function(){ // callback
    reviewUser.fadeOut();
});
```

You can also chain `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` via `.promise()` (returns the promise from the methods) since they exhibit [Promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/#example-1) behavior:

```
reviewContent.fadeOut()
    .promise()
    .done(function(){
       reviewUser.fadeOut();
    });
```

[***Demo***](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/aqzf5z6s/)